# How do I free the memory in this case?

Tags: dispose, lazarus

I have this type definition:

```
KMenuClass = class
    private
      pMenuID: String;
    public
      property MenuID: String read pMenuID;
      constructor Create(const paraMenuID: String);
  end;
```

Then I do this:

```
constructor KMenuClass.Create(const paraMenuID: String);
begin
  pMenuID:= paraMenuID;
end;

procedure TfrmPermissions.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  clSetup.Items.AddObject('ant', KMenuClass.Create('a007'));
  clSetup.Items.AddObject('cat', KMenuClass.Create('x123'));

end;
```

The above two entries aer only test entries. I'm really looking at about 50 items.
**clSetup** is of type TCheckListBox and I'm basically storing a second string along with the **Items** string.

I can output a specific item like this:

```
Var
  ThisItem : KMenuClass;
.
.
.
  ThisItem := clSetup.Items.Objects[clSetup.ItemIndex] as KMenuClass;

  ShowMessage(clSetup.Items[clSetup.ItemIndex] + ' : ' + ThisItem.MenuID);
```

But how do I dispose of my objects associated with each list item? Does it auto-dispose when I close the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually iterating over items.objects, items.count times and freeing each object is probably the only way, since the property is probably tstrings, and doesn't have an ownsobjects property (that only comes in at tstringlist).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get your point, but curiously, is it wrong if I expect it to self-dispose when the form closes?

Comment: Should I use `ThisIem.Free` or `ThisItem.FreeInstance`?

Comment: Yes, my guess is that they won't be freed upon closer. The system doesn't know if they are owned or references.  and .free